# Notation for vector composed of inner products $\langle v, \, w_i \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, terminology

A manner to represent matricially the projection of a vector $v \in V$ on a subspace $W \subset V$ is by the projective operator $\pi(v)$. The statement below represents the main procedure:

Since we may always decompose a vector $v \in V$ as tangent $v^\intercal$ and perpendicular $v^\perp$ components, the former component is the object we look for. Therefore, we may apply the inner product of both sides with a basis vector of $W$ vector space.

$$\sum\limits_j \langle w_i, \, w_j \rangle \, v^\intercal_j = \langle w_i, \, v \rangle$$

The left term multiplying $v_j^\intercal$ represents the [Gram Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) G.

Question: Do we have any notation or name for the right counterpart?

Comment: I found your notation confusing.  Presumably $\ v_j^\top\ $ (of which you haven't given an explicit definition) is the unique *scalar* such that $\ v^\top=\sum_j v_j^\top w_j\ $?

Comment: You infer precisely and correctly.

Comment: I read at the moment Willi Rinow's student Peter Dombrowski. He refers sometimes to this notation as $\langle W, \, v\rangle$. At first glance, it seems a scalar variable due to the inner product, but it is a (column) vector.